# Customizing DBTrigger message in adf

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Hi I am trying to customize DBTrigger message in bean Here is code for it, it is displaying my customized message but as well it is displaying DBTrigger message below to my message, Kindly help me  to get out of this.

```
public void saveLataActionListenerNew(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    System.out.println("----on click saved ");
    try {
        OperationBinding operationBinding = (OperationBinding)getBindings().getOperationBinding("Commit");
        Object result = operationBinding.execute();
        System.out.println("Errors : " + operationBinding.getErrors());

        if (operationBinding.getErrors() != null) {
            Iterator it = operationBinding.getErrors().iterator();
            System.out.println("error = " + it);
            System.out.println("size of Errors - " + operationBinding.getErrors().size());

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                DMLException error = (DMLException)it.next();
                String errorCause = "" + error.getCause();
                System.out.println("error.getCause() : " + errorCause);
                if (errorCause != null && errorCause.contains("ORA-00001: unique constraint")) {
                    uniqueConstraint = "Lata is Exists for given State";
                    showMessage(uniqueConstraint, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        uniqueConstraint = "Record is saved successfully";
        showMessage(uniqueConstraint, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
        System.out.println("---record saved successfully");
        //            addPlaceCodePfl.setRendered(false);
        //            addPlaceCodePgl.clearInitialState();
        //            addPlaceCodePfl.

    } catch (Exception e) {
        uniqueConstraint = e.getMessage();
        showMessage(uniqueConstraint, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: So the problem is that you get the standard ADF message as well? If so, does it only happen when your code reaches the Catch block?

Comment: i am getting error in try block itself..